# A database required for educational purposes

Tags: sql-server, database, data-warehouse

I know that the title is not pretty descriptive but I want I just want is a database, like AdventureWorks or NorthWind but other than them, to use it in my Data Warehouse course, so I need it to have mainly numeric data to be used in analysis.

Answer (score 0):

There is a DW version of AdventureWorks2012 sample database, you can download it from here:

http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/105902

Comment: I know but I didn't want either AdvetureWorks or NorthWind, I need any database other than them.

Comment: I know of any other publically available DW sample database for SQL Server. Check this link as well: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/post/Enlarging-the-AdventureWorks-Sample-Databases.aspx